# Tab content appears from side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I create a tab where the tab-content appears from the right side as a transparent layer on top of the main background?

Her is an [image](http://postimg.org/image/ovdk3f91p/) for better understanding!

I am not sure how to approach this, could someone point me to potential existing code - or should I try to create my own, by using JavaScript and/or CSS!? I also want the tab menu to be responsive, so that the tab-menus will be added to a responsive menu, some thing like [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/).

It would be great if some body could point me in the correct direction, either existing code or how is should go about to develop this on my own.

Comment: Google "slideout panel".

Comment: Now I feel stupid.. "slideout panel" is not a part of my English vocabulary ;) Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Sometimes we don't know what we don't know. Please either provide an answer to your own question and accept it, or delete the question.